# how to change location of index.html in different profiles using spring boot/maven?

Tags: java, gruntjs, spring-boot

Currently we are working `--spring.profiles.active=dev`
and the application take the front end for this folder `"src/main/webapp"`

i want to serve the application from `"src/main/webapp/dist"` when i am running in `--spring.profiles.active=stage`

the "dist" folder is generated by grunt with all the .js and .css minified files also with the index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create 2 properties files:

   `application-dev.properties` and
   `application-stage.properties`
2. Use `spring.view.prefix` property to set the prefix for your views (`spring.mvc.view.prefix` starting from version 1.3 of Spring Boot).